# Why does an aggregated set only return 100 results?

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently learning mongodb, and trying to query measurements with an aggregate query (I know that the query doesn't make the most sense but it's a simplified version).

But somehow the query always returns far too little results.

```
db.measurements.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            measuretime: {
                $gte: ISODate('2014-05-25'),
                $lt: ISODate('2014-05-26')
            },
            parameter_id: new ObjectId('54eb38fc70703cd29a8e9ae9')
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { parameter_id: '$parameter_id' },
            values: { $addToSet: '$value' }
        }
    }
]);
```

The result looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "parameter_id":"54eb38fc70703cd29a8e9ae9"
      },
      "values":[
         10.15,
         10.88,
         10.57,
         10.13,
         10.72,
         10.98,
         10.84,
         10.17,
         10.36,
         10.03,
         10.14,
         10.62,
         10.46,
         10.01,
         10.18,
         10.64,
         10.12,
         10.69,
         10.33,
         10.51,
         10.26,
         10.21,
         10.45,
         10.22,
         10.43,
         10.55,
         10.41,
         10.27,
         10.25,
         10.5,
         10.06,
         10.3,
         10.39,
         10.8,
         10.23,
         10.44,
         10.99,
         10.94,
         11,
         10.19,
         10,
         10.71,
         10.85,
         10.02,
         10.59,
         10.79,
         10.07,
         10.77,
         10.74,
         10.96,
         10.31,
         10.76,
         10.1,
         10.32,
         10.65,
         10.58,
         10.49,
         10.47,
         10.48,
         10.24,
         10.52,
         10.61,
         10.83,
         10.73,
         10.28,
         10.56,
         10.11,
         10.7,
         10.97,
         10.82,
         10.91,
         10.66,
         10.93,
         10.2,
         10.9,
         10.89,
         10.4,
         10.05,
         10.95,
         10.16,
         10.78,
         10.67,
         10.08,
         10.68,
         10.81,
         10.04,
         10.09,
         10.54,
         10.87,
         10.92,
         10.63,
         10.75,
         10.35,
         10.86,
         10.6,
         10.37,
         10.53,
         10.29,
         10.38,
         10.42,
         10.34
      ]
   }
]
```

Which is fine except that there are only 100 values in the result, but when checking with `count` it shows that there should be much more (also 100 doesn't really look like a arbitrary number).

```
db.measurements.count({
    measuretime: {
        $gte: ISODate('2014-05-25'),
        $lt: ISODate('2014-05-26')
    },
    parameter_id: ObjectId('54eb38fc70703cd29a8e9ae9')
});
```

Returns: `17286`

So is there some configuration to get more than 100 results? Or is the query simply wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$addToSet` operator removes duplicates. It appears that your original documents in `measurements` have duplicate values for the `value` field, which are discarded when inserted using `$addToSet`. You should try your query using the `$push` operator. For more information about the `$push` operator, check out [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) in the documentation.